# Fileupload Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to get full path which user selected in file upload control.
how can we do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The file upload will send you the file, with the filename, but nothing else. Giving you the full path on the users computer is both a possible invasion of privacy and a possible security breach, so it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that for security reasons. This means you can get information about any user folder structure that uploads files to your web site.

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

browser restrictions does not allow this, however there are some hints using javascript before submiting to achieve this

For instance

```
<asp:button onClientClick="document.getElementById('hiddenField1').value = document.getElementById('fileUpload1').value"  ...
```

Then the path can be retrieved on server side via hiddenField1.Value